# Mapeamento java web com xml

Tags: java, xml, aplicação-web, java-ee

Olá,

Estou aprendendo o java para web, e estou com um certo problema, não estou conseguindo fazer o mapeamento no arquivo xml para os links das paginas ficarem mais limpos.

Tenho a seguinte classe:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/exec")
public class Controller extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        HttpSession session = req.getSession();
        session.removeAttribute("itemInvalido");
        String tarefa = req.getParameter("tarefa");
        if (tarefa == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Voce esqueceu de passar a tarefa");
        }

            try {
                RequestDispatcher dispatcher;

                String nomeClasse = "br.com.portal.hidrosistemas.web." + tarefa;
                Class<?> type = Class.forName(nomeClasse);
                Tarefa instancia = (Tarefa) type.newInstance();
                String pagina = instancia.executa(req, resp);
                dispatcher = req.getRequestDispatcher(pagina);
                dispatcher.forward(req, resp);      

            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

E a classe de Login:

```
public class Login implements Tarefa {

    @Override
    public String executa(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws Exception {

        HttpSession session = req.getSession();
        Empresa empresa = (Empresa) session.getAttribute("usuarioLogado");

        if(empresa != null)
            return "/WEB-INF/paginas/pedidos.jsp";


        try (Connection con = new ConnectionPool().getConnetion()) {
            String email = req.getParameter("e-mail");
            String senha = req.getParameter("senha");

            empresa = new EmpresaDAO(con).buscaLogin(email, senha);


            if (empresa != null) {
                session = req.getSession();
                session.setAttribute("usuarioLogado", empresa);
                session.setMaxInactiveInterval(10*60);
                return "/WEB-INF/paginas/pedidos.jsp";

            }
        }catch(NullPointerException e) {
            return "/index.jsp";
        }
        req.setAttribute("erroLogin", "Usuario ou senha invalidos");
        return "/index.jsp";
    }
}
```

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

  <display-name>hidro-sistemas</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>br.com.portal.hidrosistemas.web.Login</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Porém não os links continuam da mesma forma, por exemplo após o login: “http://localhost:8080/hidro-sistemas/exec?tarefa=Login”, gostaria que ficasse /paginaInicial ou /login.

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Recomendo dar uma lida sobre [como debugar programas pequenos](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7785/como-debugar-programas-pequenos). O SOpt aprecia perguntas bem argumentadas sobre a explicação de seu problema. De resto, a pergunta está boa.